# Decode a ByteBuffer, result of an snmp trap message

Tags: java, decode, snmp, bytebuffer, snmp4j

I'm using this to receive an snmpv1 trap message:

```
transport.addTransportListener(new TransportListener() {
    public void processMessage(TransportMapping transportmapping, 
            Address address, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        BERInputStream berStream = new BERInputStream(byteBuffer);
        BER.decodeString(berStream, new BER.MutableByte());
    }
)};
```

My problem is that I do not know how to parse `byteBuffer` to obtain the data the agent sent in a clear way.
This is what I obtain if I execute my code now:

```
java.io.IOException: Wrong ASN.1 type. Not a string: 48 at position 1
```

I've tried with some other `MutableType`s but I'm really confused which one to use.
Is this correct? Do you know which `MutableType` to use if so?

Comment: Could you add an example message to your posting?

Comment: @Robert: see my answer, I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing it totally wrong.

Thanks to a colleague of mine, here's the correction (ignore the above):

```
Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
CommandResponder trapPrinter = new CommandResponder() {
    public synchronized void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent e) {
        PDU command = e.getPDU();
    }
};
```

`command` contains all the informations, no need to decode anything.